# Syncing Google Apps Directory Information to Mac Contacts over cardDAV

Tags: mac-osx, g-suite, contacts

The Problem:  Our company runs Google Apps.  Some users prefer to run native applications on their laptops, such as Mac Mail, Mac Calendar, etc.  If you are not logged in to Gmail, you will not be able to access the Google Apps Directory (what is this person's E-mail address, what is this group's E-mail address, etc.).  There could be other ways to do this, but one way that I am trying to solve this problem is by doing a Google Apps Directory sync to a laptop periodically.  Then, when the user starts up Mail, Mail can pull directory information from Contacts, and !viola!, the directory is there.

I have been struggling to get the Google Apps directory for our domain to sync up with an application in Mac OS X.  Doing some research, I have found an article from the official Gmail blog that describes the change to CardDAV for syncing Gmail contacts:

(Blog article) http://gmailblog.blogspot.ca/2012/09/a-new-way-to-sync-google-contacts.html

I have also found the Google Apps help article which describes how you can sync your contacts on your Mac using the Contacts application.  You can find that article here:  http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1366863.

I have followed the steps outlined in the Google help documentation, and the full directory is not syncing.  Despite connecting up correctly to my Google account, I cannot get any contacts to sync to my laptop running Mac OS X.

Here are a few questions that I have:

1. Is there a better way to solve this issue with Mac OS X? (specifically, Mountain Lion)
2. Has anybody tried syncing Google Apps contacts with Mac Contacts before?
3. Did it work?  Did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing contacts only works on a per user basis, eg., each persons private contact list can be synced, but the public directory probably can't be synced.  I've looked for a solution but have no luck yet.